# How to create DSN in Azure environment?

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, dsn, hosted

I'm trying to create a DSN on an Azure hosted environment using the following code:

```
    public static bool AddSystemDsn(string server, string database)
    {
        return SQLConfigDataSource((IntPtr)0,
            4, //4 = ODBC_ADD_SYS_DSN
           "SQL Server\0",
           $"SERVER={server}\0DSN={database}\0DATABASE= 
           {database}\0TRUSTED_CONNECTION=Yes\0ANSINPW=NO");
    }
```

It's returning False, but I'm not sure why. I wonder if there better code I should be using to make a DSN on an Azure environment?

Comment: Why do you need a DSN?

Comment: You may want to clarify what you mean "Azure hosted environment" - code can run in Azure in all sort of configurations from functions (where you control almost nothing) to full VM (where you control everything including what OS to use).

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](https://docs.informatica.com/integration-cloud/cloud-data-integration-connectors/current-version/microsoft-azure-sql-data-warehouse-v2-connector/pushdown-optimization/create-a-system-dsn.html) can help you to create a System DNS using ODBC driver on sql-server.